# Multiple directives requesting isolate scope to call host scope function in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I need to attach 2 callbacks to an `<input>` field, like this:

```
<input ng-model="someModel" 
       first-callback="myOwnCallback()" 
       second-callback="myOtherCallback()">
```

I tried to implement this creating 2 directives that both require an isolate scope and expose the 2 attributes with the '&' flag, like this:

```
[...]
.directive('firstCallback', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: { firstCallback: '&' },
        [...]
    }
})
.directive('secondCallback', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: { secondCallback: '&' },
        [...]
    }
})
[...]
```

This obviously doesn't work because the 2 directives are both requesting an isolate scope, which isn't possible (and there could also be some issue with ngModel scope, if one).

Here's a plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/QGc3yrjzt57lWOkd7Etb?p=preview

Anybody can tell me if there are good practices in such scenario?

Comment: explain the nature of the callbacks on the input? how are they supposed to work? Wouldn't ng-change be a 'callback'?

Comment: @EliteOctagon Yes, `ng-change` is a callback. The first one should be a _debounced_ `ng-change` (called only once after a delay), the second one a _conditional_ `ng-change` (called only if certain keys are pressed). By the way in the plnkr I linked there is the full example of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: gotcha, much clearer now

Answer (score 0):

Is there a need to break out the callbacks into two different directives?  Would something like this work?

http://plnkr.co/edit/CrqyG0H87eF3z2FlojBX?p=preview

```
.directive('debounceChangeAction', function($timeout) {
    return  {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
          debounceChangeAction: '&',
          specialKeyAction: '&'
        },
        link: function(scope,el,attrs,ngModel) {
          console.log('helo')
            var updateTimeout,
                delay = 200;
            var keys = [13,9];
          var update = function(e) {
            if (keys.indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1) {
                    scope.specialKeyAction();
                    return;
                }

                if(updateTimeout) $timeout.cancel(updateTimeout);
                updateTimeout = $timeout(function() {
                    scope.debounceChangeAction();
                }, delay);
            }
            el.on('keyup', update);
            scope.$destroy(function() {
                el.unbind('keyup');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**updated example** http://plnkr.co/edit/v0ztQEcuyYGVpq3Cv17E?p=preview

```
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('main', function($scope,$timeout) {

  $scope.myDebounceChangeAction = function() {
    console.log('debounceChangeAction', $scope.filter)
  }
  $scope.mySpecialKeyAction = function() {
    console.log('specialKeyAction', $scope.filter)
  }
})

.directive('debounceChangeAction', function($timeout) {
    return  {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
          debounceChangeAction: '&',
          specialKeyAction: '&',
          enabler:'@'
        },
        link: function(scope,el,attrs,ngModel) {
          console.log('helo')
            var updateTimeout,
                delay = 200;
            var keys = [13,9];
            var fooA=function(e){
              if (keys.indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1) {
                    scope.specialKeyAction();
                    return;
                }
            };


            var fooB = function(e){
              if(updateTimeout) $timeout.cancel(updateTimeout);
                updateTimeout = $timeout(function() {
                    scope.debounceChangeAction();
                }, delay);
            };

          var update = function(e) {

            switch(scope.enabler){
              case 'A':
                fooA(e);
                break;
              case 'B':
                fooB(e);
                break;
              case 'AB':
                fooA(e);
                fooB(e);
                break;
            }

            }
            el.on('keyup', update);
            scope.$destroy(function() {
                el.unbind('keyup');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Actually I have the need to break the functionality in 2 directives, as in some cases I need one while in other cases I need the other. In any case I need to figure out how this can be achieved as I guess this could be a quite common scenario.

Comment: In reality I could just write a single one which exposes the 2 attributes but I'd like to know how I could keep the 2 distinct..

Comment: what about creating modules, and importing them as needed for directives?

Comment: I'm not getting what you mean. Do you mean angular modules? Can you give me an example, please?

Comment: nevermind the module idea.  what about defining an additional parameter for a single directive that would be used to drive a case statement for what happens on key up?